# RewardVideo Script Energy +1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I do not know how to Reward the player with more energy after seeing the reward ad.
So I want to reward the player with Energy.
It looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details.

```
private BannerView bannerAd;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
bool isRewarded = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(InitializationStatus => { });
    this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
    this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    this.RequestBanner();
}
void Update()
{
    if (isRewarded)
    {
        isRewarded = false;
        
    }
```

I have an energy bar 250/250, once press play the energy is going to 249/250 Energy, how can I script to increase the Energy +1 when player press the reward Button?

```
[SerializeField] Text energyText;
[SerializeField] Text timerText;
[SerializeField] Slider energyBar;
private int maxEnergy = 250;
private int currentEnergy;
private int restoreDuration = 250;
private DateTime nextEnergyTime;
private DateTime lastEnergyTime;
private bool isRestoring = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("currentEnergy"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("currentEnergy", 50);
        Load();
        StartCoroutine(RestoreEnergy());

    }
    else
    {
        Load();
        StartCoroutine(RestoreEnergy());
    }
}
public void UseEnergy()
{
    if(currentEnergy >= 1)
    {
        currentEnergy--;
        UpdateEnergy();
        if (isRestoring == false)
        {
            if(currentEnergy + 1 == maxEnergy)
            {
                nextEnergyTime = AddDuration(DateTime.Now, restoreDuration);
            }
            StartCoroutine(RestoreEnergy());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Isufficient Energy!!");
    }
}
private IEnumerator RestoreEnergy()
{
    UpdateEnergyTimer();
    isRestoring = true;
    
    while(currentEnergy < maxEnergy)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime nextDateTime = nextEnergyTime;
        bool isEnergyAdding = false;

        while(currentDateTime > nextDateTime)
        {
            if(currentEnergy < maxEnergy)
            {
                isEnergyAdding = true;
                currentEnergy++;
                UpdateEnergy();
                DateTime timeToAdd = lastEnergyTime > nextDateTime ? lastEnergyTime : nextDateTime;
                nextDateTime = AddDuration(timeToAdd, restoreDuration);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isEnergyAdding == true)
        {
            lastEnergyTime = DateTime.Now;
            nextEnergyTime = nextDateTime;
        }
        UpdateEnergyTimer();
        UpdateEnergy();
        Save();
        yield return null;
    }
    isRestoring = false;
}


private DateTime AddDuration(DateTime datetime, int duration)
{
    return datetime.AddSeconds(duration);
    //return datetime.AddMinutes(duration);
}

private void UpdateEnergyTimer()
{
    if (currentEnergy >= maxEnergy)
    {
        timerText.text = "Full";
        return;
    }
    TimeSpan time = nextEnergyTime - DateTime.Now;
    string timeValue = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D1}", time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
    timerText.text = timeValue;
}

private void UpdateEnergy()
{
    energyText.text = currentEnergy.ToString() + "/" + maxEnergy.ToString();

    energyBar.maxValue = maxEnergy;
    energyBar.value = currentEnergy;

}


private DateTime StringToDate(string datetime)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(datetime))
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(datetime);
    }
}

private void Load()
{
    currentEnergy = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("currentEnergy");
    nextEnergyTime = StringToDate(PlayerPrefs.GetString("nextEnergyTime"));
    lastEnergyTime = StringToDate(PlayerPrefs.GetString("lastEnergyTime"));
}

private void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("currentEnergy", currentEnergy);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("nextEnergyTime", nextEnergyTime.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("lastEnergyTime", lastEnergyTime.ToString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can determinate if the user won at ads callback events
add this event callback

```
// Called when the user should be rewarded for interacting with the ad.
this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
```

then

```
public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
{
        //Now it's time to reward the user
        //Use those if you want to get the amount from the ad setup
        //string type = args.Type;
        //double amount = args.Amount;
}
```